# Overload =operator in C# or alternative ways to trigger a event after and before assignment?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm trying to create my own data type.
So I started with a base example of Microsoft `DynamicDictionary`.

The code is : at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx

Main part of my type

```
public class myDynType : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
{
    ....
}
```

Now I want something like this in my code :

```
[MaxAllowedValue(100)]
myDynType  SomeVar;
```

As you know we can't overload assignment in C# (= operator) so what are alternative ways to fire a event before assignment and after that ?

```
SomeVar = 7.55;   // I want to fire an event right before assignment
//Plus after assignment
```

I want to check the value before assignment to throw an exception if it's bigger than 100.
And I want to check it after assignment to round the value or modify it.

Comment: `SomeVar = "HelloWorld"` What this should do?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That would limit the string length to 100 first characters

Comment: Change `SomeVar` to a property.

Comment: @stuartd I don't want to call it with member binding! Otherwise I could overrid TrySet and TryGet to achive this.

Comment: Your code/question doesn't make any sense to me. A class cannot be assigned a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by overloading the implicit conversion (casting) operator.  For instance:

```
class MyDynType : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator MyDynType(int value)
    {
        MyDynType x = new MyDynType();
        if (value > 100)
            x.Value = 100;
        else
            x.Value = value;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
dynamic x = (MyDynType)6;
Console.WriteLine(x.Value);  // Outputs "6"
dynamic y = (MyDynType)150;           
Console.WriteLine(y.Value);  // Outputs "100"
```

For more info, see the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx).  Since you tagged VB.NET, I'll mention that the equivalent in VB.NET is to overload the `CType` operator using `Widening` modifier.

However, overloading the conversion operators can cause a lot of confusion, so you should do so sparingly, if at all.

Comment: I was just about to add something about that. +1!

Comment: `implicit` operators should not throw exceptions

Comment: Granted.  It would certainly be more consistent if it was an explicit conversion.  Then you'd *expect* that it might throw an exception.  If you are going to make implicit, it would be better to at least default the value to the max value if the given value is too high rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: This code does not work with `DynamicObject` inherited classes

Comment: @Mahdi you're not using `dynamic` in your examples. How exactly is that supposed to work? I don't see how the type can be `dynamic` and `myDynType` at once.

Comment: @TimS. myDynType is inheriting from `DynamicObject` which is same as `dynamic` keyword in C#.

Comment: @Mahdi that's not correct. It's useful if you're making an object to be used as a `dynamic` object, but it's not the same thing. E.g. `myDynType`'s override of [`TryConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryconvert.aspx) method is called when you have `int i = (dynamic)new myDynType();`, but there's no reverse (AFAIK), to dynamically have `myDynType a = 1;` (apart from the non-dynamic `implicit operator`).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I updated my answer to make it a little better.  Again, it would still be better if it was `explicit` instead of `implicit`, but you're right, it shouldn't throw and exception.

Comment: @Mahdi I updated my answer to show that it does indeed work with `dynamic`.  If it isn't working for you, please describe how you are trying to use it, exactly.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly, but maybe you can do what you need with properties:

```
myDynType someVar;
[MaxAllowedValue(100)]
myDynType SomeVar
{
    get
    {
        return someVar;
    }
    set
    {
        PreStuff();
        someVar = value;
        PostStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use it just like you use int as a type. I can't use properties outside a class space.